# How to get out of typical corporate programming

Tags: job-change, job-satisfaction

I've been programming Java EE and Spring-based Web backends for about three years now and it has become increasingly boring and life-sucking.

I studied Computer Science but never really got a degree because I was almost instantly hired to do Java development by one of the major Java houses and never found time to finish my studies (I still have that possibility though).

The main thing that bugs me about my work is maintaining and building these customer-facing products in general. I'd like to work with something more technical like maintaining open-source projects and frameworks typical developers actually use in their daily work.

Do you think there's a reasonable change to find work like this in the future and could you give me some hints on where to direct my efforts to find this sort of work?

Comment: Start looking for jobs that offer the work you want to do and apply for them...

Answer (score 4):

> Do you think there's a reasonable change to find work like this in the
>   future

If you are motivated enough and willing to work hard enough, there's always a chance to make almost any kind of change in your career.

You might want to finish up that degree in your free time. In many positions, such a degree could be a requirement.

And you should make sure you are working on open-source projects as much as time permits - particularly those related to the kinds of frameworks you wish to maintain. These sorts of jobs might be few and far between, but they do exist.

Finally, the only way you'll get such a job is by finding them and applying. Start doing that. You learn what it really takes to land such a job. If you already have what it takes, you'll be hired. If not, you'll know where to focus your efforts.

Comment: This is actually a very solid piece of advice. I think it's time to quit and get that CS degree now.

Answer (score 1):

Many people do the soul soothing work in their spare time (often for free), if you want to do it for a living either develop and maintain your own products or apply for jobs in the field you want to work in.